# IIS reverse proxy: pass accessed domain/host

Tags: tomcat, iis, reverse-proxy, tomcat8, windows-server-2016

I've configured IIS reverse proxy with Tomcat8. My site can be accessed from few domains: example.com, 1.example.com, 2.example.com, docs.example.com etc.

On Tomcat server I would like to know which exaclty domain was accessed. Is possible to pass accessed domain in IIS reverse proxy?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you used the IIS revery proxy to rewrite the url to tomcat server, it will contains the url in the http host request header.

For exmaple, I have below revery proxy rule, it will rewrite the `http://localhost:8082/` to `http://localhost:3367`.

```
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3367/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

The result:

[image]